# Maven test/resources directory and integration test

Tags: maven-2, maven, integration-testing

Hopefully should be a simple question...

I have an integration test module which contains the default directory structure:

```
src
|-main
|-test
  |-java
  |-resources
```

Then within my resources directory I have an xxxx.xml and xxxx.xsd file, and I need to load these files in as part of my test:

```
@Test
public void should_do_some_stuff_with_xml_and_xsd() // not actual test name
{
   File xmlFile = new File("xxxx.xml");
   File xsdFile = new File("xxxx.xsd");
   ...
}
```

It keeps failing trying to load the file, now I presumed it was down to me needing to give it a relative path from the project root or something. I need this test to run externally to my IDE so I can run the tests on the build server when it gets there...

So my question is, how do I target these files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The classpath mechanism does not work for files. Relative file paths are resolved from the current directory, not from the classpath elements.

So you could just do

```
File xmlFile = new File("target/test-classes/xxxx.xml");
File xsdFile = new File("target/test-classes/xxxx.xsd");
```

However, a much cleaner solution would be to work with InputStreams instead of files. Almost every library that supports `File` parameters also supports `InputStream` parameters. And that way you can use `ClassLoader` magic without manually specifying any paths:

```
ClassLoader cldr = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream xmlStream = cldr.getResourceAsStream("xxxx.xml");
InputStream xsdStream = cldr.getResourceAsStream("xxxx.xsd");
```

**Reference:**

- [Byte Streams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) (Sun Java Tutorial)
- [`ClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) (javadoc)
- [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) (javadoc)

Comment: If you really just want file instead of the input stream, you can do:  `File xmlFile = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("xxxx.xml"));`